# What does the influence_conversation parameter do?

Tags: rasa, rasa-core

From the rasa docs:

> By default, entities influence action prediction. To prevent extracted
> entities from influencing the conversation for specific intents you
> can ignore entities for certain intents. To ignore an entity for all
> intents, without having to list it under the ignore_entities flag of
> each intent, you can set the flag influence_conversation to false
> under the entity:

What does it actually mean to change the ignore_entities flag? The intent/entity combination is always processed by the NLU and can be queried in the next step in the story.. so what do they mean that it does not 'influence' the conversation?

Answer (score 0):

By not 'influencing' the conversation, it means that the dialogue flow in your story isn't affected. So what this means in simple terms is that your entity won't be used as a condition to change the dialogue. It would then be simply used to 'store' data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).